# Django Sitemap Framework. Accepting query parameters

Tags: python, django, sitemap, django-sitemaps

I'm using the [Django Sitemap Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sitemaps/)

I've no problem retrieving a list of articles from my DB.

```
class ArticleSitemap(Sitemap):
    def items(self):
        return articles.objects.filter(tagid=1399).order_by('-publisheddate')
```

I now want to accept a query parameter to filter by an inputted tag id ie:

sitemap.xml?tagid=1000

I have yet to find an example in the docs or on stack.

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to access `HttpRequest` object from `Sitemap` class. Probably the easiest way is to create your own view(s) for the sitemap(s), do what you need to do with `HttpRequest` and call Django internal view to do the final rendering of XML.

Setup your sitemap URLs as Django docs says (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#initialization), but use your own view(s).

`urls.py`:

```py
from my_app.sitemap_views import custom_sitemap_index, custom_sitemap_section

sitemaps = {
    "foo": FooSitemap,
    "bar": BarSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r"^sitemap\.xml$",
        custom_sitemap_index,
        {"sitemaps": sitemaps},
        name="sitemap_index",
    ),
    url(
        r"^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$",
        custom_sitemap_section,
        {"sitemaps": sitemaps},
        name="sitemaps",
    ),
    # ...
]
```

Your custom sitemap views are standard Django views: you can access `HttpRequest`, database, cache...

`sitemap_views.py`:

```py
import copy

from django.contrib.sitemaps import views as django_sitemaps_views
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import x_robots_tag


@x_robots_tag
def custom_sitemap_index(
    request,
    sitemaps,
    template_name="sitemap_index.xml",
    content_type="application/xml",
    sitemap_url_name="django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap",
):
    print("You can access request here.", request)

    return django_sitemaps_views.index(
        request, template_name, content_type, sitemaps, sitemap_url_name
    )


@x_robots_tag
def custom_sitemap_section(
    request,
    sitemaps,
    section=None,
    template_name="sitemap.xml",
    content_type="application/xml",
):
    tag_id = int(request.GET.get("tagid"))

    # We do not want to modify global variable "sitemaps"!
    # Otherwise sitemap instances would be shared across requests (tag_id should be dynamic).
    sitemaps_copy = copy.deepcopy(sitemaps)

    for section, site in sitemaps_copy.items():
        if callable(site):
            sitemaps_copy[section] = site(tag_id=tag_id)

    return django_sitemaps_views.sitemap(
        request, sitemaps_copy, section, template_name, content_type
    )
```

`sitemap.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap


class FooSitemap(Sitemap):
    def __init__(self, tag_id: int):
        self.tag_id = tag_id
        super().__init__()

    def items(self):
        return (
            Articles.objects.filter(tagid=1399)
            .filter(tag_id=self.tag_id)
            .order_by("-publisheddate")
        )


class BarSitemap(Sitemap):
    pass
    # ...
    # ...
```

Comment: I'm amazed that this isn't marked as the answer. Fantastic work. It's a perfect template. And now that my backend has fronted sites in different countries, being able to create country specific sitemaps with a URL param has been a dream! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Its in the request's Get-attribute:

the url '.../names/getNames?pattern=Helm' results in a request-object that has as GET : <QueryDict: {'pattern': ['Helm']}>

Comment: My issue is that I cant access the request object coming from the Django Sitemap class see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sitemaps/